# python asterisk triangle without using y* "*"

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create a iso triangle (one that starts in the middle).
I have a code but the problem is that I'm not allowed to use Y* "*" 5 in my code.
(The y is a variable there)
Also I may only use one print statement at the end of my code.
Can you please help me out.

```
f = int(raw_input("enter"))
for i in range(f):
    print " " * (f-i-1) + "*" * (2*i+1)
```

creats this triangle

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

---

---

---

---

However, you are not allowed to use the *-operator on string and int. So for example ''***'' * 3 is not allowed, but 3 * 4 is

Comment: You have one too many rows on that triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just creates a continuous string and then prints it at the end

```
f = int(raw_input("Enter height: "))
s = ''
for i in xrange(f):
    for j in xrange(f-i-1):
        s += ' '
    for j in xrange(2*i+1):
        s += '*'
    s += '\n'
print s
```

Comment: i wasned allowed to use string * int

Comment: @John I didn't use string * int. `2*i` is just `int * int`

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which i think is very easy to understand. You can make the parameter of `range()` variable, to make it more dynamic.

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(1,12,2):
    count=(11-i)/2
    for j in xrange(count):
        print(" ",end='')
    for j in xrange(i):
        print("*",end='')
    for j in xrange(count):
        print(" ",end='')
    print(end="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is using the `center()` string method:

```
f = int(raw_input("How many rows to print in the triangle? "))
star = "*"
full_string = ""
for X in xrange(f):
    star += "**" if X>0 else ""
    full_string += star.center(2*f-1) + "\n"
print full_string[:-1]
```

The `str.center()` documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center

---

EDIT: If you can't use the `print` statement within the `for` loop, you could concatenate the string during the loop and print it at the end:

```
f = int(raw_input("How many rows to print in the triangle? "))
star = "*"
full_string = ""

for X in xrange(f):
    # the first row should take only one star
    star += "**" if X>0 else ""
    star2 = star.center(2*f-1)
    full_string += star2 + "\n"

# slice the string to delete the last "\n"
print full_string[:-1]
```

I noticed that using a `for` loop add a newline character. If you want to avoid this, you can slice the string before printing.

Comment: @John, how many rows do you need to print the triangle in this example, 5 or 6?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this code, i just checked it and it worked fine. If you would post the error message we might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: The code works but it's not allowed. It uses the `'*' * 5` which isn't allowed

Comment: @SirParselot thanks i didn't quite get that, your answer is good though.